# Fluid Fixed Content

Tags: html, css, layout

What's missing to make this fluid-fixed layout work?

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="options">Opt</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{margin:0;padding:0;}
.title{margin-right:50px;}
.options{float:right;width:50px;position:relative;top:0;left:auto;}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7Sdq6/

The link below works but I can't figure out what is missing for the above example to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/show/

EDIT: I can position .options absolutely but I have a dropdown within that and I do not want the dropdown's position to be positioned relatively to .options

Comment: Did you forget to float the title left? - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/7Sdq6/1/

Comment: No the the example `http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/6vPqA/13/show/` works without floating the fluid content

Answer (score 1):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7Sdq6/2/)

just add

```
display:inline-block;
```

Instead of `margin-right: 50px` use `width: calc(100% - 50px)`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7Sdq6/4/)**

css

```
.header {
    width:400px;
}
.title {
    width: calc(100% - 50px); /* takes the width of the parent and we substract the width of the right floated div from it instead of using margin-right */
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.options {
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I read somewhere that calc() is not supported by some browsers? EDIT: Seems ok actually http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to achieve a fixed title with fluid options, so you need to use this CSS

**CSS**

```
.title {
    margin:0 50px 0 0;
    float:left;
    width: 400px /*your width*/
}
.options {overflow:hidden}
```

Comment: No the title is fluid and the options are fixed.

Comment: @AsaCarter so just change the CSS for your needs

Comment: that doesn't make sense. I cant add a width to the fluid content and if I float it, it loses the width. Would you like to create an example?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

The fixed content needs to be before the fluid content in the HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="options">Opt</div>
    <div class="title">Title</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Sdq6/5/